# How to get last day of previous month using current date?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to get the last of day of previous month using the current date:

```
var myDate = new Date();
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#description):

> if 0 is provided for dayValue, the date will be set to the last day of the previous month.

But when set date to zero:

```
myDate.setDate(0)
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDate));
```

I get "2021-08-01T01:18:34.021Z" which first day of the current month. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Running `console.log(new Date(new Date().setDate(0)));` I get `Sat 31st July 2021` so I cannot replicate your issue

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I get the same with your code. Not sure what's wrong with mine.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - Firefox version 90.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: @user8297969 What is the output with `console.log(myDate)`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman & @Unmitigated - That's it. Ugh... sorry... I should go to bed. JSON.stringify is printing in UTC and when I  `console.log(myDate)` I get "Sat Jul 31 2021 20:38:40 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` is serializing the timestamp with a `Z` timezone, indicating UTC. The difference between UTC and your local timezone is causing the date to rollover to the next day.

You can use `toLocaleString()` to print the date in your local timezone:

```js
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(0);
console.log(myDate.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: What browser does that? Firefox outputs the timestamp `1627695461640`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Try `JSON.stringify(new Date)`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox `setDate()` returns the timestamp in milliseconds. Look at the `Date` object.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `dateInstance.toString()` or `dateInstance.toLocaleString()`:

```js
const myDate = new Date;
myDate.setDate(0); myDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(myDate.toString()); console.log(myDate.toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date-fns` package

```
var df = require("date-fns")

let myDate = new Date() //Thu Aug 05 2021 22:16:09

let lastDayOfPrevMonth = df.endOfMonth(df.subMonths(myDate, 1)) //Sat Jul 31 2021 23:59:59 GMT-0400
```